# RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace and naming of group, does not allow whitespace after parenthesis?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, whitespace

Look at the following code, which you can test in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) if you want to (or [ideone](http://ideone.com/IqX1dr)):

```
void Main()
{
    var options = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;
    var reWorks       = new Regex(@"(?<a>)", options);
    var reDoesNotWork = new Regex(@"( ?<a>)", options);
}
```

I would think that the option [RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should allow both to work:

> IgnorePatternWhitespace
>   **Eliminates unescaped white space from the pattern** and enables comments marked with #. However, the IgnorePatternWhitespace value does not affect or eliminate white space in character classes.

*(my emphasis to point to the part that I feel should cover this case)*

However, it seems that the naming of the group (and possibly other sequences as well) really need to be adjacent to the group opening parenthesis, and thus I get this exception:

> ArgumentException
>   parsing "( ?)" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.

Is this a bug in the documentation, a bug in the code (ie. implementation of `Regex`), or is there something else I'm not understanding correctly here?

I discovered this when I effectively tried to write the following regex code to document the regex for future maintainers:

```
var Regex = new Regex(@"
    ...
    (
       ?<var1>          # group for first variable
       ...
    )
```

and I had to change it to this:

```
var Regex = new Regex(@"
    ...
    (?<var1>            # group for first variable
       ...
    )
```

Comment: Indeed, I think that this information had been omitted in the documentation. I seems that `(?<var>`, `(?>`, `(?:`, `(?!`, `(?<!`, `(?=`, `(?<=`, `{1,3}` are insecable strings.

Comment: Bizarelly, [Regular-Expressions.info says](http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html) that this SHOULD work. (OK, it's for the atomic group option: it says `( ?>ato mic)` should work!)

Comment: The question is, should they have been allowed to have whitespace like my code showed? One thing is how it currently works, it might be something else that was supposed to work.

Comment: @Rawling: doesn't work with PCRE too. However the PCRE documentation say that this is not allowed, Perl seems to allow this.

Comment: I filed a Connect issue with Microsoft to get them to update the documentation. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/810545/regexoptions-ignorepatternwhitespace-documentation-is-lacking-some-details-regarding-some-whitespace-that-will-fail-to-parse-the-expression

Comment: If anyone wants to write up an answer to the question, feel free, so that the question actually has an *answer* as well, not just comments.

Comment: You'd best answer the question yourself when you get a response back from MS ;)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an anomoly, it's actually quite simple if put in the right terms.

Bear with me through this...

In Regex you have a lot of different tokens.

For example, these are each individual tokens: `A`, `[`, `)`, `^`.

Also, there are character-class tokens such as `\w`, which evaluates to actual character classes like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which is just a longer list of Tokens.

White-Space can exist between any token.  However, as I just illustrated, some tokens are standalone, and some are in token structures, such as `{1,200}` which is one long structure.

Without knowing the Regex Engine, you assume the string is string-parsed and perhaps the first step was to do something like:

```
String.Replace(Input, WhiteSpace, "")
```

But when applying knowledge which we all already know, that would break our Pattern TWICE in this Regex:

```
ABCD[ ]EFGH\ IJKL
```

Yes, IgnoreWhiteSpace allows White-Space in Character-Classes, and also when escaped with a Backslash.

Now imagine this token being parsed by the Regex Engine: `.{ 2,3}`  First the Dot is parsed, then the Opening Curly Bracket... then the Regex Engine declares "I'M INSIDE A REPETITION ARRAY!!" The next character is the Minimum Repetition Number.  WhiteSpace?  That Isn't A Number!!! Break.

Now imagine this: `( ?>Blah)`.  First, the `(` is parsed, then the Regex Engine checks the next character to see if this Sub-Expression has a Special Function, and finds WhiteSpace.  **NO!**, this is not a Special Functioning Sub-Expression.  Next Token: WhiteSpace.  **Ignore The WhiteSpace.**  Next Token: QuestionMark.  The Preceding Token should be optional!... there is no preceding character, the last thing we saw was the opening of a Sub-Expression... wtf?  BREAK

Long Story Short: When working with Multi-Character Tokens, or Token Structures, they shouldn't be broken up with WhiteSpace.  White-Space isn't Removed At The Beginning, That bridge is crossed when the Token Parser gets to it.  So if the Parser gets to it an an in-opportune time inside a Token Structure, it breaks or is un-expected results.

You can't expect something like `String.Replace(Input, WhiteSpace, "")` to be part of the Regex Token Parsing Engine.  That would break so much code.

Comment: I fully understand why this works, or breaks, depending on your point of view. The *documentation*, however, says that the option eliminates whitespace. It does not say anything about *between tokens*. That's why I filed the Microsoft Connect issue as well. It should be documented.

Comment: Good call.  I just saw you waiting for an answer and knew I could give the most detailed answer.  I actually walked through the RegularExpressions Namespace and understand the serious changes they'd have to make to change it.  That code's a dang mess, lol.  But granted, the .NET Regex Engine is SOO Much more powerful than others.  A fraction slower, and able to freeze if you really (don't)? know what you're doing.  But powerful.